# Have you ever encountered a minesweeper level where just luck is involved?

Tags: minesweeper

I've encountered a problem while chilling and playing minesweeper today.

I reached the end of the game, but with two remaining slots and only 1 of them is a mine. I can't think of any logical way where I could have finished solving this without a coin flip and hoping for the best.

Was there anything I could think of to actually know the last mine location? Like, is there any known pattern? Is this normal for you? I don't remember encountering these problems back in the days.

Please find the board below:

[image: Unsolvable by logic puzzle]

Comment: Just from experience, I have a lot of games that end up as coin flips.

Answer (score 1):

On harder difficulties is a common situation, as [discussed here](https://nothings.org/games/minesweeper/). There's no strategy for those cases, only luck is involved:

> There is no way of getting any further information about the likely location of the one mine that remains in these two spaces. It's a 50-50 chance--a toss of a coin. When you find something like this, you're probably better off taking a guess right away, rather than saving it for later--so if you guess wrong, you won't have wasted a lot of extra time solving the rest of the board.

An example of unlucky board:

[image]